# org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, oracle, classcastexception

connection file

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
Context context = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");

//The JDBC Data source that we just created
DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("connpool");
this.con = ds.getConnection();
this.des=ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("ARRAY_INT",this.con);

System.out.println("in set array1");
this.arr_to_pass=new ARRAY(this.des,this.con,arr);
this.csmt.setArray(index, this.arr_to_pass);
```

but i got the following exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Comment: I'm having similar issues, could you put your this.con class and how is defined your jndi datasource (java:comp/env)?

Answer (score 2):

I guess `ClassCastException` is thrown at this line

```
this.con = ds.getConnection();
```

Your code doesn't show the type of `this.con`, but it must be an `OracleConnection`. You can't do that, because connection is a wrapped dbcp connection.

If you want to take Oracle Connection, you have to unwrap it before with `BasicDataSource.unwrap(Class<T> iface)`. You can also use `BasicDataSource.isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface)` before, to check if the wrapped connection is of Oracle Connection type, to avoid casting exception :)

For example:

```
if (ds.getConnection().isWrapperFor(OracleConnection.class)) {
    this.con = ds.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
}
```

Comment: this.con type is a Connection it is not an Oracle Connection and i tried your solution but it gives the exception..javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial  but it doesn't give exception with my original code

Answer (score 0):

If you get below error ,make sure you have got connection with database

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection at

If there is no connection then you may get this error.